# Why won't Chrome expand console.dir?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I use `console.log(res)`, the result is:

```
Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

If I use `console.dir(res)`, the result is

```
Object
```

where Object has a triangle to expand, but it wont expand.

Comment: I usually convert it to JSON and then log it to the console with `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`, but your example works fine for me.  Are there no arrows next to it that you can use to navigate the object?

Comment: There is an arrow. but when I click it, nothing expands. There is a blue 'i' with the tooltip "Value below was evaluated just now"